# Which word in given statement is closest in meaning to "strikingly"?

Tags: word-choice

The technology of the North American colonies did not differ strikingly from that of Europe.
The word "strikingly" in this statement is closest in meaning to :

```
a. Realistically
b. Dramatically
c. Completely
d. Immediately
```

I choose B but my friend A. What is the answer and why, Can you help me ?

Comment: To strike someone has the effect of focussing the attention of the strikee. The idea is sudden, often revelatory, perception. _That struck me as a brilliant idea_. The adverb form means 'in a striking manner', which leaves out everything except _dramatically_, the only choice that refers to emotion and perceptions at all.

Comment: Thanks. Good explanation. Why you dont answer this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the answer B. , simple because if you chose any other word the sentence loses its meaning.